# How to trigger multiple counter_cache in one model as has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, counter-cache

I have 3 models(Allen, Bob, Chris) which are polymorphic with Join model. and a User model which connect with the  join model.

```
class Allen < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joins, :as => :resource
  ...
end

class Bob < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joins, :as => :resource
  ...
end

class Chris < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joins, :as => :resource 
  ...
end

class Join < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :initiator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "user_id"
             :counter_cache => "How to write with 3 different counter cache?"

  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => :resources_count
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :joins
  has_many :allens, :through => :joins, :source => :initiator

  has_many :initial_joins, :class_name => "Join"
end
```

My question is how to write the counter cache for Bob, Chris and Allen in User Model

or you can review it here: https://gist.github.com/1350922

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's no standard way to achieve this. Add an `after_create` callback to your `Allen`, `Bob` and `Chris` where you would get the list of all `User`s associated with this particular `Bob` and recalculate `bobs_count` for each of them manually.